# Why is my JS not reading my <input> correctly?

Tags: javascript, random

This is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Random Number Generator</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>
      Random Number Generator
    </h1>
    <p>
      Minimum:
      <input type="number" id="min" />
    </p>
    <p>
      Maximum:
      <input type="number" id="max" />
    </p>
    <button onclick="go()">
      Go
    </button>
    <p id="ran"></p>
    <script>var min, max;
function go() {
  min = document.getElementById("min").value;
  max = document.getElementById("max").value;
  document.getElementById("ran").innerHTML = Math.floor(
    Math.random() * (max - min + 1) + min
  );
}
</script>
  </body>
</html>
```

It is a random number generator.
My problem is that the result is less than the minimum.
I'm positive that the problem is with the input because one time I replaced max and min with numbers and it came up with a number between them.

Comment: use `min = document.getElementById("min").valueAsNumber`

Comment: `Math.floor( Math.random() * (max - min + 1) + min );` should be `Math.floor( Math.random() * (max - min + 1) ) + min;` - you need to multiply -> round down the multiplication result -> *then* add the minimum. Not multiply -> add minimum -> round down the whole result.

Comment: Thanks, ```document.getElementById("min").valueAsNumber``` worked.